# cannot login via gui for ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, lightdm

I just turned on my computer today and just couldn't get past the lightdm login screen. The login screen is 640*480 instead of the usual 1920*1080, and after I entered the password and clicked "login", the machine would emit a failure sound after a short pause. The same happens to guest login. TTY login is fine. As I have a RNN project due Friday I would like to get it working ASAP.

I think it might be related to the graphics driver but I cannot narrow down on the issue. I installed CUDA 8.0 from Nvidia for Tensorflow-gpu which wasn't a fan of Noveau, so I had <strike>it</strike> Noveau uninstalled, and since then the Ubuntu loading screen prior to the login screen has been 640*480. The latest change I made prior to the error was probably `sudo apt-get install golang`

Specs:

- Acer G3-710 w/ Nvidia 1070
- Ubuntu 16.04
- Nvidia driver 375.66

`systemctl status lightdm.service` returns:

- PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet5.so
- PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so

Things attempted:

1. rm .authority file(ownership is user)
2. use gdm (somehow won't work, some error causes 'stopping user manager uid 121' and causes extremely flickery tty that prevents me from operating, had to go to recovery mode to switch back to lightdm)
3. purging and reinstalling lightdm

Comment: When you uninstalled CUDA you also uninstalled the Nvidia drivers. If you no longer need CUDA then don't install it but DO install the recommended Nvidia drivers for your card.

Comment: @MichaelBay I did not uninstall CUDA, but I uninstalled Nouveau, which was the default graphics driver for 16.04. Things has been working in the interim, but I suspect that a change of the dependencies somehow broke it.

Comment: CUDA works with Nvidia drivers **only**.  And CUDA **installs** Nvidia drivers (and there's no need to uninstall nouveau, it should be kept as a fallback). So... Here's the thing: CUDA installs a very **specific version of drivers** that most likely are **NOT compatible** with your graphics card. Speaking of which, please [edit] and post the hardware sepcs. Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelBay I made several attempts installing CUDA with Nouveau intact, but none went through. Eventually I had to purge Nouveau and black list it in order to install CUDA. The version of driver that came with CUDA is 375.26, which supports 1070 and I nonetheless updated to 375.66 (the newest) after the installation.

Answer (score -1):

Resolved by painstakingly downloading and reinstalling nvidia 375.66 driver